# Facebook like button started to 0

Tags: facebook, api

Hello last time I started to have a problem with facebook like button for my fanpage.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button

Every other fanpage urls work but my fanpage shows always 0 likes. It started to happen 3-4 days ago. What should be the problem? My fanpage is banned or what? Every other fb api works expect the like button.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/426149314385861/